# SageMaker ANSI escape codes

Tags: dockerfile, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker, ansi-escape

I'm using a library in a SageMaker training script that includes print statements with characters like tabs. When I look in my SM cloudwatch training logs, they're filled with ANSI escape codes like `#011` (in place of tabs). This makes the logs much more difficult to read.

Is there any way I can prevent this behavior? Whether that be through a modification of my `Dockerfile` or my `train.py` script?

Comment: `#011` isn't an ANSI escape code

Comment: @ThomasDickey Sorry, not sure the proper terminology. When I print it outside of SageMaker I see whitespace (presumably tabs), and when I look in cloudwatch logs that whitespace is replaced with `#011`.